# Generating a random number within a range c++

Tags: random

I'm trying to generate a random number between 20 and 54. 
The code I'm currently using is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int y=rand() % 35 + 20;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    return 0;
}
```

Each time I reset the program the numbers generated are the same:

```
$ ./main
28
$ ./main
28
$ ./main
28
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where/how are you using `srand()?`. Also, [Generate random numbers uniformly over an entire range](//stackoverflow.com/q/288739)

Comment: Helpful viewing: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). Very informative and quite funny.

Comment: Please limit your asking to one question per question. The answer to why you're getting the same random sequence every run is vastly different from how to ensure concurrent numbers have a difference of at least 5. I would vote to close as too broad if I hadn't already used my vote on the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up `srand` which is used to seed the random generator. Typically, people pass it a value that changes from run to run, like the current epoch time. Call it just once.

Also, note that modern C++ includes better random features: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random . There's really tons of options there.

In order to do:

> but so each concurrent number is not within 5 of the number before?

The simplest (and most inefficient) is to test the condition and generate a new number if needed, in a `while()` loop. If you want cleaner, you can simply generate a number in a smaller range (11 number smaller) and skip the used area. Try it and come back with code and specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you're not changing the seed before generating numbers. See the manual for [srand(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/srand).

Then again from [what](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) I've heard, using modulo might introduce some artifacts in the generation.

Anyhow if you're using C++11 you really should go with the STL way:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 gen(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dis(20, 54);

    std::cerr << dis(gen) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> so each concurrent number is not within 5 of the number before?

you sample from a restricted range, based on your previous value.

Here is (most of) a [*RandomNumberDistribution*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution) that does this.

```
struct dissimilar_int_distribution
{
    dissimilar_int_distribution() = default;
    dissimilar_int_distribution(param_type p) : p(p) {}
    dissimilar_int_distribution(int low, int high) : p(low, high) {}

    using result_type = int;

    template<typename URBG>
    int operator()(URBG & urbg)
    {
        return (*this)(urbg, param);
    }

    template<typename URBG>
    int operator()(URBG & urbg, param_type & p)
    {
        int result;
        if (!p.prev)
        {
            std::uniform_int_distribution dis(p.low, p.high);
            result = dis(urbg);
        }
        else if (*p.prev - 5 <= p.low)
        {
            std::uniform_int_distribution dis(*p.prev + 5, p.high);
            result = dis(urbg);
        }
        else if (p.high <= *p.prev + 5)
        {
            std::uniform_int_distribution dis(p.low, *p.prev - 6);
            result = dis(urbg);
        }
        else
        {
            std::uniform_int_distribution dis(p.low, p.high - 11);
            auto inter = dis(urbg);
            result = (inter < (*p.prev - 5)) ? inter : inter + 11;
        }

        p.prev = result;
        return result;
    }

    int min() const
    {
        if (!param.prev)
        {
            return param.high;
        }
        else if (param.high <= *param.prev + 5)
        {
            return *param.prev - 6;
        }
        else
        {
            return param.high;
        }
    }

    int max() const
    {
        if (!param.prev)
        {
            return param.high;
        }
        else if (*param.prev - 5 <= param.low)
        {
            return *param.prev + 5;
        }
        else
        {
            return param.high;
        }
    }

    struct param_type
    {
        int low;
        int high;
        std::optional<int> prev;
    };

private:
    param_type param;
};
```